# JS: Expand position:absolute parent when dynamically adding relative divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using absolutely positioned containers to slide screens left and right on "Next" and "Back". You can see this here: http://opencdesign.herokuapp.com/offer

Click "Got it" to move to 2nd screen, which is where the problem lies. If you click "Add item or category" enough times, the inputs will expand past the footer.

What is the simplest way to expand the height of the window as I add inputs? I'm also open to an alternative method of sliding screens left and right than using absolute positioning.

**HTML**

```
<div id="offer-2">
      <div class="row one-margin-bottom">
        <div class="small-12 medium-11 small-centered columns">
          <h5 class="">What share of purchases will you accept in Currents?</h5>
          <!-- <a class="offer-info-popup_open"><i class="half-margin-right fa fa-lg fa-question-circle"></i>How it works</a> -->
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row left">
        <div class="small-12 medium-6 small-centered columns">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-left small-3 columns">
              <p><strong><img class="" src="{% static 'img/symbol-navy.svg' %}"/> share</strong></p>
            </div>

            <div class="input-right small-9 columns">
              <p id="item-title"><strong>Item or category</strong></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 medium-6 small-centered columns">
          <div id="item-1" class="row collapse">
            <div class="input-left small-3 columns">
              <div class="relative">
                <input name="discount-amount-1" type="number" class="fit-left qtr-margin-right" placeholder="20" value="20"/>
                <span class="input-icon-right">%</span>
              </div>
              <!-- <span class="input-sizer"><select name="discount-type-1">
                <option selected>% of</option>
                <option>$ of</option>
              </select></span> -->
            </div>

            <div class="input-right small-9 columns">
              <div class="fit-left half-margin-top one-margin-right one-margin-left">of</div>
              <div class="relative input-sizer">
                <input name="item-name-1" type="text" placeholder="Item or category name" value="All products" class="good-cat" />
                <i class="remove-input alert fa fa-times"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="item-2" class="row collapse">
            <div class="input-left small-3 columns">
              <div class="relative">
                <input name="discount-amount-2" type="number" class="fit-left qtr-margin-right" placeholder="20" value="20"/>
                <span class="input-icon-right">%</span>
              </div>
              <!-- <span class="input-sizer"><select name="discount-type-1">
                <option selected>% of</option>
                <option>$ of</option>
              </select></span> -->
            </div>

            <div class="input-right small-9 columns">
              <div class="fit-left half-margin-top one-margin-right one-margin-left">of</div>
              <div class="relative input-sizer">
                <input name="item-name-2" type="text" placeholder="Item or category name" value="All services" class="good-cat" />
                <i class="remove-input alert fa fa-times"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <a id="add-item" class=""><i class="half-margin-top fa fa-plus-circle half-margin-right"></i>Add item or category</a>

          <div class="row one-margin-top">
            <a class="prev-offer button round secondary">Back</a>
            <a class="next-offer button round">Next</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
    var id = 3

    $('#add-item').click(function(){
      $(this).before('<div id="item-'+id+'" class="row collapse hidden"><div class="input-left small-3 columns"><div class="relative"><input name="discount-amount-'+id+'" type="number" class="fit-left qtr-margin-right" placeholder="20" value="20"/><span class="input-icon-right">%</span></div></div><div class="input-right small-9 columns"><div class="fit-left half-margin-top one-margin-right one-margin-left">of</div><div class="relative input-sizer"><input name="item-name-'+id+'" type="text" placeholder="Item or category name" /><i class="remove-input alert fa fa-times"></i></div></div></div>');
      $('#item-'+id+'').slideDown();

      id ++
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could potentially target the div with a CSS rule and handle its `overflow-y` with `scroll` (or increase its size, if you want to expand it). For a quick example, using jQuery, you could have a condition followed by `$('#mydiv').css("overflow-y", "scroll");` (though it doesn't look like that div currently has an ID or custom Classname, so feel free to change that to whatever works best).

Alternatively, you could use a second, hidden div which is a parent to this one, and expand the hidden div. By using a relative size, you'd be able to fill into the invisible parent =)

It looks good, though!

Comment: Thanks! Not following everything with scroll though. Could you provide a fiddle?